# Get django-registration and django-profile working together

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-registration

I am in process to setting up a new django project and I want to use the provided apps django-registration and django-profile. I installed both of them with easy-install and managed to get the django-registration working fine. My next step would be to connect the django-profile app to the working branch. The django-registration offers a service, that redirects to a URL, which is defined in the settings.py-variable LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL. My guess was, that I can simply paste a url of the django-profile app to connect both. (e.g. '/profiles/'). 
My settings.py-variable AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE is set on 'registration.User', (trying to use the django-registration model!).
But I get a 
    SiteProfileNotAvailable at /profiles/
    No exception supplied
error.
I tried to follow these steps:
https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/tip/docs/index.rst
https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/src/tip/docs/overview.txt
But i am not sure, if I done everything properly, namely this paragraph from overview.txt

> For default use, create a profile model for your site and specify the
>   `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` setting appropriately. Then add `profiles`
>   to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting, create the appropriate templates
>   and set up the URLs. For convenience in linking to profiles, your
>   profile model should define a `get_absolute_url()` method which
>   routes to the view `profiles.views.profile_detail`, passing the
>   username.

So my questions are:

- Is that a well known error?
- Is it the right way to set 'registration.User' as AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE?
- What is ment by "should define a `get_absolute_url()` method which
  routes to the view `profiles.views.profile_detail`, passing the
  username." in the overview.txt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

django-registration is hard to use thanks to the type of documentation and lack of templates. Many Django developers now use django-social-auth instead:

https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth
http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

You can see how Kenneth Love integrated it into the Django Packages code base here:

https://github.com/opencomparison/opencomparison/blob/master/apps/profiles/views.py#L83
https://github.com/opencomparison/opencomparison/blob/master/settings.py#L277